# Middle URL Parameter in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to route a path with parameters in the middle. This is my routes look like.

```
import Events from "./views/EventsView";
import Event from "./views/EventView";
import NotFound from "./views/NotFoundView";
import RegistrationView from "./views/RegistrationView"

export default [
  {path: "/", component: Events, exact: true},
  {path: "/events", component: Events, exact: true},
  {path: "/events/:projectId", component: Event, exact: true},
  {path: "/events/:projectId/register", component: RegistrationView, exact: true},
  {component: NotFound}
]
```

Then I map my routes inside a `<Switch>` which inside a `<Router>`.

```
<Switch>
    {
        return routes.map(({path, component, exact}, key) =>
            <Route key={key} path={path} component={component} exact={exact}/>)
}
</Switch>
```

I use `Link` to access the `Event` component.

```
<Link to="/events/1234">Title Here</Link>
```

**Problem**

The problem is my  `/events/:projectId` is getting overridden by path `/events/:projectId/register`. So every-time I try to access my `Event` component. I got RegistrationView returned. I try to change `exact` value or remove the `<Switch>` but it seems like doesn't work like that.
Anyone has a problem with this one? How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Remove the exact on the route of the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{path: "/events/:projectId/register", component: RegistrationView, exact: true},

{path: "/events/:projectId", component: Event, exact: true},
```

The route with :projectId/register needs to be on top.

Comment: @ZulwiyozaPutra did you tried my suggestion it has something to do with the route exact property you need to remove the exact on the child routes that has param and only have one on the events

Comment: yes, it works after remove the corresponding `exact: true`